# Sequential function names using preprocessor

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I'm writing a simple unit-testing library in C to run some tests on code, and am curious if it is possible to make the process more efficient using macros/the preprocessor. Yes, I realize that I probably shouldn't be writing my own, but I would still like to know if this is possible.

Here's how I currently do it:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

/* Each test exits with status 1 if fail */
void test_00() { ... }     
void test_01() { ... }
...
void test_09() { ... }

#define NUM_TESTS 10
void (*TESTS[NUM_TESTS])() = {test_00, test_01, ..., test_09};

/* Only want to run the test number passed in on the command line */
int main(int argc, char *argv) {
  int test_num = atoi(argv[1]);    // Error checking in actual code
  TESTS[test_num]();
}
```

In particular, I am interested in getting rid of the `TESTS` array where I have to manually add in every new test that is made. Ideally, have it be automatically generated using `NUM_TESTS` since it's honestly always repetitive.

It doesn't have to be particularly general, I won't have more than 100 tests cases so 2 digits for the test number is fine, and all the tests are named in exactly the same way.

---

Sorry if this question doesn't follow some guidelines. I have no reasonable attempt to show, and am at a loss for what exactly to even look for.

Comment: Well, you can do it with preprocessor, but it's a string replacement - you'll end up listing all possible cases anyway. `Each test exits with status 1` Note your tests return `void`. `Ideally, have it be automatically generated using NUM_TESTS` Ideally, you would not need `NUM_TESTS` either :)

Comment: You may want to look [here](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=16234213).

Comment: But why do you need `NUM_TESTS` anyway? Why not `void (*TESTS[])() = { the tests.. }`?

Comment: @KamilCuk it's convenient to know the number of tests. In my main I have ```if (test_num >= 0 && test_num < NUM_TESTS)``` to verify the command line argument. Also, my tests don't return anything, they exit the program with status 1.

Comment: You know the number of tests from `sizeof(TESTS)/sizeof(*TESTS)`... `if (test_num >= 0 && test_num < sizeof(TESTS)/sizeof(*TESTS))` would work the same way

Comment: Makes sense, but honestly getting rid of NUM_TESTS is not really a concern for me. It's nice to know it can be done. I updated my earlier comment re: the return values

Comment: Check out Boost.Preprocessor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could dynamically load and call the symbol at runtime by using `dlsym()`.

```
// compile with `gcc -Wall -o test -Wl,--export-dynamic test.c -ldl`
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>


/* Each test exits with status 1 if fail */
void test_00() { exit(10); }     
void test_01() { exit(11); }
void test_09() { exit(19); }

/* Only want to run the test number passed in on the command line */
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   void (*test)(void);
   char symname[32];

   snprintf(symname, sizeof(symname), "test_%s", argv[1]);
   if ((test = dlsym(NULL, symname)) == NULL)
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
      exit(1);
   }

   test();
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Not what I intended but accomplishes exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
// Provide the counts as macros:
#define TEST_LISTS_0() test_00
//$ for i in $(seq 1 10); do echo "#define TEST_LISTS_$i() TEST_LISTS_$((i-1))(),$(printf "%02d" "$i")"; done
#define TEST_LISTS_1() TEST_LISTS_0(),test_01
#define TEST_LISTS_2() TEST_LISTS_1(),test_02
#define TEST_LISTS_3() TEST_LISTS_2(),test_03
#define TEST_LISTS_4() TEST_LISTS_3(),test_04
#define TEST_LISTS_5() TEST_LISTS_4(),test_05
#define TEST_LISTS_6() TEST_LISTS_5(),test_06
#define TEST_LISTS_7() TEST_LISTS_6(),test_07
#define TEST_LISTS_8() TEST_LISTS_7(),test_08
#define TEST_LISTS_9() TEST_LISTS_8(),test_09
#define TEST_LISTS_10() TEST_LISTS_9(),test_10
// etc.

// Then just reexpand the macro expansion with the prefix:
#define TEST_LIST_GEN_IN(x)  TEST_LISTS_##x()
#define TEST_LIST_GEN(x)  TEST_LIST_GEN_IN(x)

#define NUM_TESTS 10
void (*TESTS[NUM_TESTS])() = {TEST_LIST_GEN(NUM_TESTS)};
```

> have it be automatically generated using NUM_TESTS since it's honestly always repetitive.

When using gcc compiler (or just a compiler that supports that) you can use a `section` and put pointers to tests in there.

```
#define XCONCAT(a, b) CONCAT(a, b)
#define CONCAT(a, b) a##b

// adds a pointer to the test function inside section tests
#define ADD_TEST(TEST_FUNCTION)  \
__attribute__((__section__("tests"))) \
void (*XCONCAT(_test_, __LINE__)) = TEST_FUNCTION

void test_01() {
    printf("%s\n", __func__);
}
// registers the test
ADD_TEST(test_01);

void test_02() {
    printf("%s\n", __func__);
}
ADD_TEST(test_02);

int main() {
    extern void (*__start_tests)();
    extern void (*__stop_tests)();
    int count = &__stop_tests - &__start_tests;
    printf("%d\n", count);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        (&__start_tests)[i]();
    }
}
// will print 2 test_01 test_02
```

Comment: Yes, I realize that I could essentially write an external script to come up with the code to define the tests array and paste in the code, but the whole point is to not have to explicitly have code for each test case. I don't really see how this is really better than my current approach.

Comment: As I said, preprocessor is text replacement. There is no "for" in preprocessor. You'll end up writing all the cases anyway, just behind a macro. You can use `m4` preprocessor and generate the C source code from it. You can checkout other projects that have a FOREACH macro already done for you, like P90 or boost.preprocessor.

Comment: I understand that, my thinking was that I would be able to do something line `TEST_LIST_GEN` using the actual function names, without the individual `TEST_LISTS_XX`. I thought some recursion is possible in preprocessor macros, I was hoping to reply on those. I guess it's not as easy as I thought it would be, thanks anyway!

Comment: The second approach seems good enough to me. Thank you!